# Код не обрабатывается

Tags: php, ооп

```
<?php
class Index
{
    public function getBody()
    {
        echo $this->getMenu();
    }
    private function getMenu()
    {
        $menu = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/menu.php');
        return $this->replaceStringMenu($menu);
    }
    private function replaceStringMenu($menu)
    {
        $main = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/main.php');
        return str_replace("%menu%", $menu, $main);
    }
}
?>
```

Вызываю на главной `getBody()`, и код из `menu.php` обрабатывается как `html`, что сделать что бы как `php` обрабатывался?

**Обновление**

С include обрабатывает код, только вот я меняю выражение блока меню, а результат выводится просто вверху страницы

```
<?php  require_once '/index.class.php'; $obj = new Index; $obj->getBody(); ?>
```

Comment: сделать ему include?

Comment: <?php echo getBody() ?>

Comment: Как вызываете покажите?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать `eval($obj->getBody);`, если вы хотите *выполнить код* из файла. [Документацию](http://www.php.su/eval), конечно же, прочтите заранее.

Только, может быть, вам всё-таки хранить меню, например, в .ini-файле?

Comment: Изменил формат на .ini, и использовал `eval` . результат тот же

Comment: Вам надо еще заменить в `getBody` `echo $this->getMenu();` на `return $this->getMenu();`.
Но расширение верните, пожалуйста, обратно. Ini-файлы спокойно отдаются настроенным по умолчанию веб-сервером, не нужно, чтобы каждый их видел. Я имел ввиду, что вам бы строить меню из конфигурационного файла, а не делать текстовую замену в исполняемом файле. Так и до php-injection недалеко...

Comment: какая разница в `getBody()` `return` или `echo`, тогда на главной надо будет выводить `getBody()` , но работает одинаково. А как строить меню из конфиг файла?

Comment: Разница принципиальная: вернуть текст дальше (и корректно передать в `eval`) или _вывести тест в стандартный поток_. 
Меню строить несложно: вы читаете конфиг в массив, например, и по каким-нибудь правилам выводите те или иные пункты меню.

Comment: `eval` ругается на `"<"` но я вставляю `php` код в `html`  а потом хтмл вместе с пхп передаю в `eval`,без скобок никак

Answer (score 0):

Исправил наконец)

```
<?php
class Index
{
   public function getBody()
   {
      return $this->getMenu();

   }
   private function getMenu()
   {
      ob_start();
      include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/menu.php');
      $menu = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      return $this->replaceString("%menu%", $menu);
   }
   private function replaceString($pattern, $menu)
   {
      $main = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/main.php');
      return str_replace($pattern, $menu, $main);
   }
}
?>
```